# Apache not restricting domain/subdomain port combinations

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have encountered an issue when I want to restrict the on domain/subdomain combinations to particular ports.

For example when I just want the following domain/subdomain port combinations to work

```
https://domain.com:99001
https://subdomain.domain.com:99003
```

I find that not only do they work but the combination below also works yet am trying to prevent it from happening

```
https://domain.com:99003
https://subdomain.domain.com:99001
```

The script below is what am using to try achieve that objective

```
<VirtualHost *:99001>
    #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias MYSERVER

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key


    <Location />
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Location>

    ProxyPass / http://11.11.11.20:99011/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://11.11.11.20:99011/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:99003>
    #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias MYSERVER

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

    <Location />
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Location>

    ProxyPass / http://11.11.11.20:99013/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://11.11.11.20:99013/
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For name-based virtual hosts, Apache uses the `ServerName` directives and any `ServerAlias` directives together with the port number to identify which virtual host should receive a particular incoming request.  In your case, requests for the alternative port must not match any virtual host, or in other words, the `ServerName` directive and any `ServerAlias` directives must be unique across all virtual hosts.

In addition, the use of a `ServerAlias` directive suggests that you are using a security certificate capable of securing multiple domains.  If the domains on the certificate(s) are shared between the virtual hosts, the issue described above is compounded because the request continues without sending a security certificate error to the client.

Comment: Does that means I cannot achieve my objective?

Comment: Isolating traffic to each virtual host is possible. However, in your configuration, it appears that your `ServerAlias` directives are shared between the two name-based virtual hosts, so Apache (correctly) sends traffic to both virtual hosts. (Although it is **possible** there is a subtle bug in Apache.) In order to separate the traffic using name-based virtual hosting, these names **must** be unique. How else could Apache distinguish between them? An alternative to making the names unique would be to use IP-based virtual hosts, using two IP addresses, one for each of the two virtual hosts.